# Database/XAMP/MYSQL: Primary key

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a database and nearly all the tables have a primary key that I created out of the scenerio. Is this allowed or do I have to find a primary key from the data.

For instance:
I have the data: Sales Assistant ID, Branch ID - I created a primary key "SalesId".

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you want?

Comment: if you are given data and instead of listing primary keys in them, you create random ones and group them with the data that's relevant EG: A Branches that contains Location and BranchID . Is that allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating your own PK is a great idea; just keep in mind that with most common MySQL engines including MyISAM and InnoDB, your PK is also going to be your Clustered Index (can only have 1 per table; do some research on Index types to see why a Clustered Index is a big deal).  Depending on the the frequency of read/insert/update operations against the table, this can have a significant impact on performance.

I almost always have an auto-incremeneting INT column called `ID` that I make my PK; it has no relation to the original data, regardless of what the Table is storing.  It is nothing more than a unique identifier of a numeric type, which combine to make it very fast to search/join.

There's arguments for finding more beneficial PKs but to start out, creating your own is completely ok and fairly common.

Comment: Thanks man! I was worried their , since my lectures "house style" is to find elements from the data. Guess I just get marked down for that :/

Comment: It's great IF you can find a PK in the data but your focus should be on picking whatever will make the most sense/make your queries the most efficient.